# Improving Video Playback by Playing Videos in Chunks

Tags: reactjs

I want to make video playback smoother in my React application, and one approach I'm considering is playing videos in chunks. I've been researching ways to achieve this, but I haven't found a working solution yet. Here's my current code:

```
import React from 'react';

const LoadVideoInChunk = () => {
    return (
        <>
            <h2>TestVideoPlayer</h2>
            <br />
            <br />
            <div style={{ padding: '29px', width: '900px' }}>
                    <video width="640" height="369" controls preload="metadata">
                        <source
                            src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/BigBuckBunny.mp4"
                            type="video/mp4"
                        />
                    </video>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

export default LoadVideoInChunk;
```

I'm looking for guidance on how to play videos in chunks in React to enhance the video playback experience. Can someone provide a working solution or suggest a better approach to achieve smoother video playback?